# Is there a better way to give arbitrary order to records in Postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql, rest

I'm trying to create an API that returns ordered JSON list(order can be specified by the client). I tried implementing this by set a float column for each record on application side(-1 for append to the front, +1 for append to the last, /2 for insert between the elements).

However, since I know there's sequence type on Postgres, I wonder if there is a better way to implement this.

Given requirements:

- If order is not specified, append a record to the last.
- Otherwise, record can be inserted in any position.
- Client can delete a record in any position.
- Response list order is guaranteed.

Comment: What do you do to insert the record into the first position if you already have ar record with order value of -1?
How many records do you expect to have in your table. More importantly - how many of them are expected to be specifically ordered?

Comment: If -1 is already there, insert a record that is -2(sorry for lack of detailed explanation). I expect roughly 100 at the most.

Answer (score 0):

To start with - [sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) is just a "counter" to be used in auto-generated fields. It is used when you need a an always increasing integer value. I don't think it is possible to use it the way you require.